# How to append datasets with same variable names but different numeric values within?

Tags: append, stata

I am having difficulty appending datasets from multiple different years. I have made sure that the variable names are the same across the different datasets. However, within the numeric variables, the labelling is different--so that in one data set Catholic=1 but in another one Catholic=11. This causes the data to get messed up when appending. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You should `decode` all such variables to string before `append`ing and `encode` the results back again.

Comment: Is there a way to create a loop that does that to automate the process?

Comment: If you think it could be true of all numeric variables, then you should `decode` them all.  `ds` will tell you which numeric variables have value labels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short snippet which you can use to `decode` all variables with value labels:

```
ds, has(vallabel)

foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
decode `var', gen(`var'x)
drop `var'
ren `var'x `var'
}
```